# How to make Spring Boot support Java-based language?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jolie

I'm working on a studies project and my objective is to extend Spring Boot framework so that it is able to handle Jolie language. My main problem is how to even enhance/extend Spring Boot to support other language - what needs to be created?

I think I am supposed to achieve something like [Kotlin support for Spring Boot](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-boot-kotlin/), but still I am not sure what conditions must be met in order to succeed at it.

Answer (score 1):

I will give a go in answering your question. Let's start from the fact that the Jolie interpreter is coded in Java. This should make inserting Jolie into a Java-based framework as Spring Boot.

I imagine that you would like to create Jolie microservices and run them from inside your framework, on this note, there is an excellent Montesi Blog post that explains how to [Run Jolie from Java](https://fmontesi.github.io/2015/01/30/running-jolie-inside-of-java.html).

In the post you can see the use the [Interpreter](https://github.com/jolie/jolie/blob/master/jolie/src/jolie/Interpreter.java) to lunch your JOLIE code inside your host java application the `class Interpreter` can be found in the jolie.jar
Another little hand on your project can come from a `jolie2java` this tool creates the java code for the message type.

```
jolie2java --addSource [true] --format [java|gwt] --packageName package_namespace [--targetPort inputPort_to_be_encoded] file.ol
```

here is an example

```
    type op1Request :void{
      .name:string
      .surname:string
    }

    type op1Response :void{
      .registrationNumber:string
    }
    interface TestInterface {
    RequestResponse:
      op1(op1Request)(op1Response)
    }

and this are the resulting java classes



 package org.matiho.springboot;
    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.LinkedList;
    import jolie.runtime.Value;
    import jolie.runtime.ByteArray;

    public class op1Request {
    private String _surname;
    private String _name;

    public op1Request( Value v ){
    if (v.hasChildren("surname")){
    _surname= v.getFirstChild("surname").strValue();
    }
    if (v.hasChildren("name")){
    _name= v.getFirstChild("name").strValue();
    }
    }
    public op1Request(){
    }
    public String getSurname(){
    return _surname;
    }
    public void setSurname( String value ){
    _surname = value;
    }
    public String getName(){
    return _name;
    }
    public void setName( String value ){
    _name = value;
    }
    public Value getValue(){
    Value vReturn = Value.create();
    if((_surname!=null)){
    vReturn.getNewChild("surname").setValue(_surname);
    }
    if((_name!=null)){
    vReturn.getNewChild("name").setValue(_name);
    }
    return vReturn;
    }
    }
```

The response class

```
package org.matiho.springboot;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import jolie.runtime.Value;
import jolie.runtime.ByteArray;

public class op1Response {
private String _registrationNumber;

public op1Response( Value v ){
if (v.hasChildren("registrationNumber")){
  _registrationNumber= v.getFirstChild("registrationNumber").strValue();
}
}
public op1Response(){
}
public String getRegistrationNumber(){
  return _registrationNumber;
}
public void setRegistrationNumber( String value ){
  _registrationNumber = value;
}
public Value getValue(){
  Value vReturn = Value.create();
  if((_registrationNumber!=null)){
  vReturn.getNewChild("registrationNumber").setValue(_registrationNumber);
  }
return vReturn;
}
}
```

I can see you running into some problems with libraries compability when importing Jolie into a framework
Hope it helps
PS: can you add the tag Jolie